# Have any published sefarim referenced research done on Mi Yodeya?

Tags: jewish-books, stackexchange

I recently saw an ad for Otzar HaChochma in one of the Jewish magazines, where they claimed to have done a search in their database, and found an obscene number of self-references where recently published sefarim referenced research done in their search engine.

**Have any published sefarim referenced research done on Mi Yodeya?**

Comment: I assume you're not counting [Mi Yodeya Publications](http://s.tk/miyodeya)

Comment: @IsaacMoses ....for simplicity's sake, let's not ;)

Comment: Not a sefer per se, but a [published academic paper](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22judaism.stackexchange%22+sienna&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C21) _has_ cited [a Mi Yodeya answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/23211/1498)! (PS - I find that dubious scholarship, but it's still awesome) [HT](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/23194/whats-the-meaning-of-hashmal-electricity-in-modern-hebrew-in-the-bible-ez#comment126565_23211) @IsaacMoses

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/980/is-mi-yodeya-helpful?rq=1

Comment: While this is on-topic on MY, I think it'd be of more interest on [meta.MY](//meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/). In other words, I'm not saying I'll migrate it thither, but am asking whether you, Shokhet, want me to do so.

Comment: @msh210 I hear what you're saying, but I think that it will probably be more seen here rather than there (since, I think, most people don't spend a lot of time on Meta)

Comment: Using the same search engine as @CharlesKoppelman above, here's another paper which cites a MiY question (footnote 41 on page 16). http://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:690200/FULLTEXT01.pdf

Comment: @Bachrach44 If I could understand what it was saying I might figure out which answer to give a bounty to :P

Comment: @Shokhet Not that I can read Swedish either, but according to google translate, this is what it says: "As mentioned earlier in the essay, Judaism has a holistic kroppssyn where body and soul is a unit. In Hebrew there is a word, nefesh which discloses humans as a whole. A distinction is therefore not on the mind and body in the same way as in the Swedish language or other languages[footnote]"

Comment: @Bachrach44 Great minds think alike: see http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18544265#18544265 and following messages.

Comment: If they used m.y, would they acknowledge it?

Comment: @Shalom Well, the academic papers that Isaac Moses found did....if I put out a *sefer* that I felt that MY really helped me with, I would acknowledge it, certainly.

Comment: not so on topic, but [this paper](http://soundideas.pugetsound.edu/faculty_pubs/2981/) grew out of a discussion on mathematics.SE, which I think is super cool

Comment: @Matt Interesting. How'd you find out about that?

Comment: I found it (by searching); a friend had told me that they were thinking of publishing of something that started as an answer he wrote on SO, so we wondered if there were any academic articles that started that way

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2970/papers-that-originated-on-math-se/5054#5054

Comment: @Matt That's pretty neat. There's a similar Meta [over here](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/507/2072); I suppose a lot of SEs will have similar things.

Comment: I think the biggest one is at cs, but it makes me think that this question should be moved to meta.... or, since the *study* of how Torah is studied is also talmud Torah, this website is an exception.... should we ask on the meta.meta.judaism.SE? Why don't we have that yet?

Comment: http://xkcd.com/1447

Comment: @Matt I linked to that xkcd on MYM, [this morning](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3375/5323) :P ....msh210 offered to migrate to meta, earlier, but I turned him down.

Comment: that's really funny, I promise I didn't see that (pure coincidence)

Comment: Some more academic papers that @IsaacMoses found: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38077154#38077154

Comment: Should this be on Meta MY?

Comment: @DonielF ....did you read the comments above? I think you're the *third* person to suggest this. Can you elaborate a little more on your suggestion?

Comment: @Shokhet I did read through, must’ve missed msh210’s comment the first time. I‘m not exactly sure whether this is off-topic, necessarily, but the focus seems to be more about content of the site - hence, a question for Meta, which is dedicated to questions about the site.

Comment: On a different note, http://www.torahforum.org/Halachos_of_Superheroes.pdf references https://Judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10806